# Android App not connecting to HTTP WEBSERIVE

Tags: android, api, android-studio, http, https

I keep target SDK version is 28.  And my webservice is HTTP.

and added this code

```
added this xml file: network_security_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_domain.com</domain>
</domain-config>
```

added these 2 lines of code in manifest file:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

But still not connecting to server.

Please help me.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: manifest file]

[image: network config file]

[image: error]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? try adding this to the manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`and make sure that `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` is inside the application tag in manifest

Comment: Would you add log please?

Comment: @MateoHervas please check manifest file screenshot sir

Comment: @DannySilva Please see the attached error message sir

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your `<application/>` tag.

```
<uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
```

like this :

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```